Characters in comments huddled together after latest PyCharm update
After updating to the latest version of PyCharm, it renders characters like this

when i place my cursor between 'b' and 'e'. It's really annoying, and it prevents me from editing single character. How to solve this problem? Lots of thanks.
THESE WORDS ARE PLACE HOLDERS SINCE STACKOVERFLOW REQUIRES ME TO ENTER MORE WORDS. THESE WORDS ARE PLACE HOLDERS SINCE STACKOVERFLOW REQUIRES ME TO ENTER MORE WORDS. THESE WORDS ARE PLACE HOLDERS SINCE STACKOVERFLOW REQUIRES ME TO ENTER MORE WORDS. THESE WORDS ARE PLACE HOLDERS SINCE STACKOVERFLOW REQUIRES ME TO ENTER MORE WORDS. THESE WORDS ARE PLACE HOLDERS SINCE STACKOVERFLOW REQUIRES ME TO ENTER MORE WORDS. THESE WORDS ARE PLACE HOLDERS SINCE STACKOVERFLOW REQUIRES ME TO ENTER MORE WORDS. THESE WORDS ARE PLACE HOLDERS SINCE STACKOVERFLOW REQUIRES ME TO ENTER MORE WORDS.
